# Convert multiple columns to a single integer with bitwise operation in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with thousands of rows describing say some product. It has multiple columns about the features of the product. For e.g.

```
productid productname isOnSale HasVeteranDiscount IsTaxExempt Otherdata1 Otherdata2 ...
1         rice        0                  1        1          info1      info2
2         camera       1        0                   0         info3      info4
```

Another table

```
[Productparts]
Partid parentproductid isGeneric CanBeSoldSeperate OtherData1 Otherdata2 ...
```

Another table:

```
ProductId ItemsSold Datesold
1          23        4/20/2013
```

I have an enum that describes productfeature:

```
[Flags]
public enum ProductFeature : short
{
    None = 0,
    isOnSale = 0x001,
    HasVeteranDiscount = 0x002, 
    IsTaxExempt = 0x004, 
    isGeneric = 0x008, 
    CanBeSoldSeperate = 0x010,
}
```

For statistical analysis I need to insert the above data from the three tables into one table as a bitwise or'ed integer of all applicable product features with the count of the products that fall into that category along with product sale counts such as:

```
ProductTrend
ProductFeatures ItemsSold MonthSold
```

For e.g if a product isonsale and has one or more part which is generic and has one or more part which can be sold seperate then its 25. 
And another product hasveterandiscount and has one or more parts that can be sold seperate then its 18 [HasVeteranDiscount | CanBeSoldSeperate = 18]
My table should look like:

```
ProductTrend
ProductFeatures ItemsSold MonthSold
25              34        April
18              12        May
```

The most important part here which I need help is how do I combine the data about the product from multiple columns in multiple tables into one single integer column productFeatures with bitwise operations.

Comment: Thanks Andomar and 1010101 (your name itself is so bit oriented you aught to know this :)) for both the bitwise solution and SQL fiddle. I used to use regextester for regex and other stuff for html and xml editing online and now I learnt about SQL fiddle. This solution worked perfect for me.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server supports `|` for bitwise or:

```
select  productid
,       productname
,       case when isOnSale = 1 then 1 else 0 end |
        case when HasVeteranDiscount = 1 then 2 else 0 end |
        case when IsTaxExempt = 1 then 4 else 0 end as Flags
from    Table1
```

[Example on SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e35b/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

try this , [sample here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01f6d4/3)

```
    select productid,intheMonthOf,features,sum(itemsold) as TotalSoldItems 
   from (

    select  a.productid,Datename(month,datesold) as intheMonthOf, itemsold,

    case when a.isonsale =1 then 1 else 0 end |
    case when a.hasveterrandiscount =1 then 2 else 0 end  |
    case when a.istaxexempt =1 then 4 else 0 end |
    case when b.isgeneric =1 then 8 else 0 end |
    case when b.canbesoldseparate =1 then 10 else 0 end as features

     from t1 a
    left outer join t2  b on a.productid=b.parentproductid
    inner join t3 c on c.porductid=a.productid )main
    group by productid,intheMonthOf,features
```